# How to open different ranges depends on the cell selected in ComboBox

Tags: vba, combobox, range, cell, selected

I have shop names in column B to E in sheet 'home'.  I need to open the corresponding range of shops in second, third, fourth and fifth sheets using a ComboBox. 
Suppose 
When selecting column B active sheet should be second one and for row number 1,2,3... Range one two three...so on. Same in other sheets also.

Now I am using select case for each Range.

Codes are below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Select Case ComboBox3

  Case Worksheet("home") . Range ("A2")
            Application.Goto Worksheet("P1").Range("A1:F20")

  Case Worksheet("home") . Range ("A3")
            Application.Goto Worksheet("P1").Range("A21:F40")

  Case Worksheet("home") . Range ("A4")
            Application.Goto Worksheet("P1").Range("A41:F60")

  Case Worksheet("home") . Range ("A5")
            Application.Goto Worksheet("P1").Range("A61:F80")


  Case Worksheet("home") . Range ("B2")
            Application.Goto Worksheet("P2").Range("A1:F20")

  Case Worksheet("home") . Range ("B3")
            Application.Goto Worksheet("P2").Range("A21:F40")

  Case Worksheet("home") . Range ("B4")
            Application.Goto Worksheet("P2").Range("A41:F60")

  Case Worksheet("home") . Range ("B5")
            Application.Goto Worksheet("P2").Range("A61:F80")

End Select

End Sub
```

Please help someone. I'm beginner in VBA. 
how to simplify this using Range offset and cell reference.?
Please help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, this site isn't a free coding service so if you include no code that you need help with, you're not going to get any help here.

Comment: Thank you for guidance. I m a beginner here. I ll edit my post.